# bind to css visibility

Tags: aurelia

Using Aurelia's css bind you have to use this syntax

```
<div css.bind="{visibility: someField ? 'visible':'hidden'}">
```

is there a more succinct way  to do this?

Please note, using `show.bind` is not what i'm after as this is equivalent to `display:none` and I actually want `visibility:hidden` (so the element takes up its space but is not visible)

Something like this would be ideal

```
<div visibility.bind="someField">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little simpler syntax would be:

```
<div css=“visibility: ${someField ? 'visible':'hidden'}”>
```

To make this more succinct, you can easily create a custom attribute:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class VisibilityCustomAttribute {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    valueChanged(newValue) {
        this.element.style.visibility = newValue ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<template>
  <require from='./visibility-custom-attribute'></require>
  <div visibility.bind="someField">
</template>
```

See [this GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=b3302999510abc037829c7687670ee3b) for an example.

Comment: this works on a regular template however I have noticed when the view is used on a `Dialog` and `someField` is not a simple boolean (e.g. its a string or calculated field) then the `valueChanged` method is never called!

Comment: @wal Are you talking about the aurelia-dialog plugin? If so, maybe there is a bug in the plugin.

Comment: yep the `aurelia-dialog` - i will report it to them